# Call API have duplicate Data and output 500 arry

Tags: javascript, json

i need some help in my code

if see the visit api url you will see Large Data duplicated

```
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/globaldothealth/monkeypox/main/latest.json';



async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
```

How we Can Merge all data and Sum it like to show have 500 infected named Confirmed And SUSPACKTED
AND SHOW IT BY Numbar

Answer (score 0):

You simply need an object to store and count the cases while iterating over the array of persons. Find an implementation below:

```js
const url =
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/globaldothealth/monkeypox/main/latest.json";

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

function getResults(data) {
  const results = {
    confirmed: 0,
    suspected: 0,
  };
  data.forEach((person) => {
    switch (person.Status) {
      case "confirmed":
        results.confirmed ++;
        break;
      case "suspected":
        results.suspected ++;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
  return results;
}

(async function () {
  const data = await getData();
  const results = getResults(data);
  console.log(
    `${results.confirmed} confirmed cases\n${results.suspected} suspected cases.`
  );
})();
```